# How to add alias with sed, double quotes and apostrophe into .bashrc

Tags: bash, sed

The alias I try is as follows:

```
al crin='sed "s/^/\'/g" lst>lst2;'
```

Escaping double quotes does not help, still getting

> unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: Look up how quoting works.

Comment: you can also use a function.. `crin() { sed "s/^/'/g" lst > lst2 ; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no escape mechanism inside single-quoted strings.  Every character represents itself, until the closing single-quote, which is necessarily the first one encountered.  Change to a double-quoted string:

```
al crin="sed \"s/^/'/g\" lst>lst2;"
```